# value wholeTextFiles is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Scala code like below :-

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark._

object RecipeIO {

val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Recipe_Extraction"))   

def read(INPUT_PATH: String): org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String)]= {


 val data = sc.wholeTextFiles("INPUT_PATH")
 val files = data.map { case (filename, content) => filename}
 (files)

 }
}
```

When I compile this code using sbt it gives me the error : 
value wholeTextFiles is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext.
I am importing all of which is required but it's still giving me this errror.
But when I compile this code by replacing **wholeTextFiles** with **textFile**, the code
 gets compiled.
What might be the problem here and how do I resolve that?
Thanks in advance!

**Environment**:

Scala compiler version 2.10.2
spark-1.2.0

**Error**:

```
[info] Set current project to RecipeIO (in build file:/home/akshat/RecipeIO/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/akshat/RecipeIO/target/scala-2.10.4/classes...
[error] /home/akshat/RecipeIO/src/main/scala/RecipeIO.scala:14: value wholeTexFiles is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext
[error]  val data = sc.wholeTexFiles(INPUT_PATH)
[error]                ^
[error] one error found
[error] {file:/home/akshat/RecipeIO/}default-55aff3/compile:compile: Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 16 s, completed Jun 15, 2015 11:07:04 PM
```

My build.sbt file looks like this :

```
name := "RecipeIO"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "0.9.0-incubating"

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "8.1.2.v20120308" 

ivyXML := 
<dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" name="javax.servlet" rev="3.0.0.v201112011016">
<artifact name="javax.servlet" type="orbit" ext="jar"/>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo: it should be `wholeTextFiles` instead of `wholeTexFiles`.

As a side note, I think you want `sc.wholeTextFiles(INPUT_PATH)` and not `sc.wholeTextFiles("INPUT_PATH")` if you really want to use the `INPUT_PATH` variable.

Comment: It's not a typo.See my question again

Comment: @AkshatKumar Please, add the error message you are receiving in the question.

Comment: Done that! @kaktusito